# create a method that sets textlabel.text to nsarray at index(x) while x<nsarray.count objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an **`NSArray` from a text file** with

```
void arrayfromfile {

// get a reference to our file
NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"CalendarQuotes" ofType:@"txt"];

// read the contents into a string
NSString *myFile = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// split our string into an array
NSArray *mySplit = [myFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];}
```

Now what I'd like to do is set `label.text` to `mySplit[x] while x< mysplit.count` and call it every time a user swipes up.

```
setlabeltextmethod quote {
if x<mySplit.count {
label.text = mySplit objectatindex x
x+=1
else { label.text = @"thats it folks" }
}
```

What I'm having trouble with is accessing `mySplit` from the quote so I can manipulate it to give me the quote at index x.

When I tried to access it from my swipe method:

```
- (IBAction)swipeUp:(id)sender {

[self doAnimationUp];
NSLog (@"swipedUp");
NSLog(@"array%@" , [mySplit objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"arraycreated");
//I'm using NSLog for debug purposes but this is where I would setlabeltext.text to mySplit objectAtIndex
}
```

I get `array[null]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mySplit` variable is *local* to `arrayfromfile`, so once that method returns the variable has gone. There is more than one approach to solving this. One is making it an *instance* variable, that is a variable that belongs to your current class instance and is visible to every instance method. Start you implementation like this:

```
@implementation MyClassName
{
    NSArray *mySplit;
}
```

Now set the variable in the instance method `arrayfromfile` and read it in the instance method `swipeUp` - both calls must be made in the *same instance* of your class, each instance has its own set of instance variables.

Other options include adding a property to the class or, if you must, a global variable of some kind.

HTH

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was something like that.